# Can I use Ampscript to remove the last character from a URL?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, substring

I am attempting to remove the last character from a URL string. Can I achieve this using Ampscript? 
It seems like it might be possible using `lenght()` and `substring()` and `subtract()` but I can't seem to bring them together to achieve this.

Comment: Did you try `%%=Substring('abcdef',2,2)=%%` ? See : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/Substring.htm

Comment: thanks for the response. Yes I did, however I won't always know the length of the URL, so can't specify in advance where to start the substring or the maximum lenght.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using the `Substring(1,2,3)`, `Length(1)` and `Subtract(1,2)` functions.

It is pretty easy and you need to supply the original string, the index you want to start with (1) and the length minus one as maximum length.

**Example code:**

```
%%[
    Var @firstString, @newString
    Set @firstString = "https://example.com/asdf/"
    Set @newString = Substring(@firstString, 1, Subtract(Length(@firstString), 1))
]%%
```

**Related documentation:**

- [Substring](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/substring/)
- [Length](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/length/)
- [Subtract](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/subtract/)

Comment: You are welcome!